# Grouping a flattened LINQ resultset

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, grouping

I have a query which produces a flattened result set, but I don't actually want it flattened, I need to group it.

```
var test = (from a in _activityNoteService.GetAll()
    from l in a.ActivityNoteLines
    where l.POItemId == poItem.Id && a.ActivityTypeId == 1
    from s in l.StockCatalogueItem.StockInventoryItems
    where s.OriginalActivityNoteLineID == l.Id
    select new
    {
      sii = s.Id,
      sci = s.StockCatalogueItem,
      po = a.PurchaseOrder
    }).ToList();
```

The `sii` values are the unique records I'm interested in, the `sci` and `po` values are common (i.e. duplicated).  How can I refactor this so it returns one `sci`, one `po` and list of `sii` records

Comment: Take a look through the various LINQ operators.  One should stand out as an operator that might be useful in grouping the items in your collection by some value.

Comment: @Servy - You must subscribe to the teach a man to fish philosophy

Comment: @Aducci Absolutely.  Just doing someone's work for them is only ever harmful to everyone involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = (from a in _activityNoteService.GetAll()
    from l in a.ActivityNoteLines
    where l.POItemId == poItem.Id && a.ActivityTypeId == 1
    from s in l.StockCatalogueItem.StockInventoryItems
    where s.OriginalActivityNoteLineID == l.Id
    group s by new { sci = s.StockCatalogueItem, po = a.PurchaseOrder  } into g
    select new
    {
      ListOfSii = g.Select(s => s.Id),
      g.Key.sci,
      g.Key.po
    }).ToList();
```